# Parsing error feature file Cucumber with NTLM-Auth installed

Tags: parsing, cucumber, cypress, ntlm-authentication

I installed Cypress (v3.8.3) and cucumber-preprocessor (v2.0.1) and that worked. After the installation of ntlm-auth (v2.1.0), cypress don't recognize anymore feature file of cucumber.

Error :

```
C:\Workspace\Cypress\cypress\integration\Google.feature:1
Feature: Google page
             ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. I need help please.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be any compatibility issues between these packages.

Have you check your ntlm configuration ?

This issue might help you with your problem https://github.com/bjowes/cypress-ntlm-auth/issues/96

Cheers !

Comment: it was helpfull ! Thx dude !
I had two "module.exports". I had to merge them !